# Unable to send data from react to express server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express

I am trying to send data from react to express server.

React code:

```
const imageRenderer = async () => {
  const res = await axios({
    method: "post",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/previewRender",
    data: selectedFile.filePaths,
  });
console.log(res.data);
```

};

Express code:

```
app.post("/previewRender", (req, res) => {
  var fileLocation = req.body;
  console.log(fileLocation); 
});
```

However in console the filelocation is shown as undefined. selectedFile.filePaths is of type object. Can't I send object to express?

Comment: We only see small part of your code so it's hard to guess but if I had I'd check if you use body-parser middleware in your Express app

Comment: I haven't used any body parser.

Comment: You need body parser for file read. Check this https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you use `app.use(express.json())` in your app.js?

Comment: Please use the comment section when you require more details regarding the question and post it as an answer only when it actually answers the question :)

Comment: Using this worked in my case

Answer (score 0):

Add this in app.js `(app.js)` or your root file of the app to post req

```
app.use(express.json());

app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
```

Put this middleware in `app.js` above your routes...